# How to set version of the prerelease NuGet according to the latest released NuGet automatically?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have two pipelines, release and prerelease.

In release pipeline version set up like this, the counter for the patch and manually set major/minor version:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  majorVersion: '1'  
  minorVersion: '1'
  patchVersion: $[counter(format('{0}.{1}', variables['majorVersion'], variables['minorVersion']), 0)]
  productVersion: $[format('{0}.{1}.{2}', variables['majorVersion'], variables['minorVersion'], variables['patchVersion'])]
```

In prerelease pipeline I manual check what is the version for all major, minor and patch from the latest release, I only add Build.BuildNumber in the end to declare it as a prerelease:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  majorVersion: '1'  
  minorVersion: '1'
  patchVersion: '2' <!-- if the last release patch version was 1, in the next prerelease I need here 2-->
  productVersionBeta: $[format('{0}.{1}.{2}-{3}', variables['majorVersion'], variables['minorVersion'], variables['patchVersion'], variables['Build.BuildNumber'])]
```

In the end I pack and push NuGet.

---

What I would like to have in my prerelease pipeline is:

```
variables:
 solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

  majorVersion: $(SOMEHOW_GET_LATEST_MAJOR_RELEASE_VERSION) 
  minorVersion: $(SOMEHOW_GET_LATEST_MINOR_RELEASE_VERSION) 
  patchVersion: $(SOMEHOW_GET_LATEST_PATCH_RELEASE_VERSION) + 1

  productVersionBeta: $[format('{0}.{1}.{2}-{3}', variables['majorVersion'], variables['minorVersion'], variables['patchVersion'], variables['Build.BuildNumber'])]
```

---

Is it possible to get the behavior as described with only yaml config because I didn't find anything about it?

If it's not possible to do just through the config then I found this REST API [The Artifact Details - Get Package Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20package%20version?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). Is there a clean way to implement it inside the pipeline for the same purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is not possible out of the box and you need to use REST API. Please check this example:

```yaml
variables:
  orgName: 'thecodemanual'
  packageId: '8e0deb67-89bd-499f-ae8c-1d3814be540a'

steps:
    - pwsh: |
       
        $url = "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/$(orgName)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/packaging/Feeds/devops-manual/Packages/$(packageId)?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
        $packageInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
        Write-Host "Pipeline = $($packageInfo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

        $version = $packageInfo.versions[0].version

        Write-Host $version

        $sp = $version.Split(".")

        echo $sp

        $majorVersion = $sp[0]
        $minorVersion = $sp[1]
        $patchVersion = [int]$sp[2] + 1
        $productVersionBeta = “$majorVersion.$minorVersion.$patchVersion-$(Build.BuildNumber)”

        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageVersion]$version"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=majorVersion]$majorVersion"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=minorVersion]$minorVersion"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=patchVersion]$patchVersion"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=productVersionBeta]$productVersionBeta"
      name: initial
    - pwsh: |
        Write-Host 'packageVersion: $(packageVersion)'
        Write-Host 'majorVersion: $(majorVersion)'
        Write-Host 'minorVersion: $(minorVersion)'
        Write-Host 'patchVersion: $(patchVersion)'
        Write-Host 'productVersionBeta: $(productVersionBeta)'
```

Latest version of my package (I got `packageId` from this endpoint `https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/devops-manual/Packages?api-version=6.0-preview.1`) is `2.1.2` and with above pipeline I get these values:

```
packageVersion: 2.1.2
majorVersion: 2
minorVersion: 1
patchVersion: 3
productVersionBeta: 2.1.3-20200901.6
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to auto set preview version of nuget.

It is [GitVersion](https://gitversion.net/docs/build-server-support/build-server/azure-devops).

With the following `GitVersion.yml`

```yml
next-version: 1.1
mode: ContinuousDelivery
increment: Inherit
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
#source-branches: ['master', 'develop', 'hotfix']
ignore:
  sha: []
  commits-before: 2018-01-01T00:00:00
branches:
  master:
    regex: master$
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
  release:
    regex: r(elease$|(eleases)?[-/])
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
  feature:
    regex: f(eatures)?[-/]
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: alpha
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
```

`GitVersion` can auto set version of Nuget.
If I tag a commit in `master` branch with `v1.1.0`,Then I commit and push an another in `Development` branch,The `1.1.0-alpha.x` will be created in  Artifact.

For more information, please refer to the blog:[Automatically increase the semantic version using GitVersion](https://blog.walterlv.com/post/automatically-semantic-versioning-using-git-version-task.en.html)